# Detecting a Changing Variable R

Tags: r

I have a data.frame as such.

```
data.frame(color = c("G","G","G","R","R","R","R","R","R","R","G","G"),
           trial = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4))
```

I want to detect when the `color` switches for each 'trial'.  Like this:

```
   color trial swtch
1      G     1     0
2      G     1     0
3      G     1     0
4      R     2     1
5      R     2     1
6      R     2     1
7      R     3     0
8      R     3     0
9      R     3     0
10     R     3     0
11     G     4     1
12     G     4     1
```

I know how to accomplish this with a `for` loop.  But is there a simple way to accomplish this in R.  I thought maybe the `ave` function would be useful.

Comment: can the color switch more than once in each trial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something a little different:

```
x <- interaction(dat,drop=TRUE)
x <- factor(x, levels=unique(x))
levels(x)[] <- 0:1
dat$swtch <- x

#   color trial swtch
#1      G     1     0
#2      G     1     0
#3      G     1     0
#4      R     2     1
#5      R     2     1
#6      R     2     1
#7      R     3     0
#8      R     3     0
#9      R     3     0
#10     R     3     0
#11     G     4     1
#12     G     4     1
```

Comment: I like this a lot... but it gives a not so nice warning if the number of levels is odd. is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: @CarlosAlberto - warnings are just that, a warning, not an error. You could `suppressWarnings(levels(x)[] <- 0:1)` but then that kind of kills the simplicity of the code.

Comment: Agreed... and I like that the code is robust to many switches in each trial.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `ave` by creating a logical index of comparing the adjacent elements of 'color', grouped by 'trial', and get the `cummax`.

```
 with(df1, ave(c(FALSE,color[-1]!= color[-nrow(df1)]), 
                 trial, FUN= cummax))
 #[1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1
```